# cannot close accordion toggle after open

Tags: javascript, jquery

I can't make my accordion close. It opens on click, however when I click back it doesn't close.

Here is my code:

```
MYPRO.accordion = function () {
 var   $acpanel = $(".accordion > .accordion-content"),
       $acsnav = $(".accordion > .accordion-title > a");      

      $acpanel.hide().first().slideUp("easeOutExpo");
    //  $acsnav.first().addClass("active");
      $acsnav.on('click', function () {
          var $this = $(this).parent().next(".accordion-content");

          if ($this.addClass("active")){
          $acsnav.removeClass("active");
          $acpanel.first($this).slideDown();
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown("easeOutExpo");
          }
          else
          {
               $acpanel.first($this).slideUp();
                 $(this).parent().next().slideUp("easeInExpo");
              //$acsnav.removeClass('active').slideUp("easeInExpo");  
              }
          return false;
    });  }
```

Comment: `if ($this.addClass("active"))` should be `if ($this.hasClass("active"))` instead ?

Comment: No. If i add `if ($this.hasClass("active"))` the toggle doesnt open at all

Comment: Can you share a fiddle with your entire code ?

Comment: Please check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/shebas/avfkc780/)

Answer (score 0):

Every time you click, `$this.addClass("active")` returns a jQuery object, so the if will allways evaluate as true, and slide down the tab, never reaching the else statements.

Try something like:

```
var $acpanel = $(".accordion > .accordion-content"),
    $acsnav = $(".accordion > .accordion-title > a");

$acpanel.slideDown("easeOutExpo");
$acsnav.addClass("active");
$acsnav.on('click', function(e) {

  if ($acsnav.hasClass("active")) {
    $acsnav.removeClass("active");
    $acpanel.show().slideUp("easeInExpo");
  } else {
    $acsnav.addClass("active")
    $acpanel.hide().slideDown("easeOutExpo");
  }
});
```

This way you'll first check if its active. If so, slide up and remove the active class. If not active, slide down and remove the active class.

Here is a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6n8jgvgc/6/).

**Edit:** Updated code and added JSDFiddle.

Comment: still same @lluchmk

Comment: Just edited the answer with a JSFiddle. Hope it helps.